# Query data by date parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I'm trying to query all data with dates that are greater or equal to `>=` than the current date.

Note:

- The format of the dates in the `columndate` column is `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- I used `database`,`table`,`columndate` to represent the database,table, and column for simplicity.
- MySQL 5.5 (version)

//STATEMENT

```
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE columndate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120);
```

**Question:** Why is my sql statement failing?

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why are you converting current date to a varchar? Compare the dates, not some strings.

Comment: @jarlh I changed it sorry just populated so tagged it. Also I as doing VARCHAR(10) so it would only print the date not time.

Comment: First, what does your table layout look like, and second, (say it with me now) **What does the error message say?**

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax First, do you know how to read... second the error msg is 1064 which isn't very specific, I'm guessing it has to do with the CONVERT but clearly examples I looked aren't working.

Comment: I do know how do read, @JordanDavis, but I can't read what isn't there, like the ***type*** of your date column. Second, however obscure an error message might be, odds are good someone might be able to suss it out, but ***only if you tell us what it says.***

Comment: Well, obviously *I* don't know how to read either. Neither did I see the error message in your request, so I didn't know whether you got an error or merely not the data expected, nor did I see a description on columndate's data type. A date, a datetime or a string? Your explanation that the format is YYYY-MM-DD suggests it to be a string, as a date has no format.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax yes your right I should of listed the `type` I didn't understand what you were saying when you said table layout, that def would of helped I'll make sure of it next time.

Comment: ... and 1064 is a "parse error," which should be accompanied by a text message indicating approximately where in the query the error occurred.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax and it did somewhere in the `CONVERT` but I couldn't figure out where it was specifically all the examples I looked at used that same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE columndate >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: @JordanDavis Glad i helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),columndate,120) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120);
```